# Single char always at the end of vector string in R

Tags: regex, r, string

I have a vector with strings that I want to manipulate in R.
Something like this:

```
c("sffssf/", "sfs/fs", "aaad")
```

I want to have a certainty that I always have one "/" at the end of each string, but sometimes their already is a "/" at the end of a certain string (or somewhere else).

I saw `str_sub` from `stringr` package,
and I thought maybe I can remove the last char conditionaly if it's a "/".
And always add a "/" afterworths.

How can I do that, or is their a better method?

Comment: `sub('/?$', '/', c("sffssf/", "sfs/fs", "aaad"))`

Comment: @RichardScriven Yeah, the comment: paste0(tests, ifelse(substr(tests, nchar(tests), nchar(tests)) != "/", "/", "")) works, Also the sub, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need `stringr` for this (though it'll work), as the base R regex capability is quite sufficient. All you really need is

```
sub('/?$', '/', c("sffssf/", "sfs/fs", "aaad"))
## [1] "sffssf/" "sfs/fs/" "aaad/"
```

`sub` looks for the first parameter (the pattern), in the third (the vector), and replaces it with the second (the replacement). Here, `'/?$'` tells it to look for a `/`, if it's there (i.e. 0 or 1 times) `?`, followed by the end of the line `$`. Since the replacement is a `/`, it'll take out a `/` that is at the end of the line (if there is one), and add in a `/`, giving you what you need.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_replace` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(v1, "/*$", "/")
#[1] "sffssf/" "sfs/fs/" "aaad/"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("sffssf/", "sfs/fs", "aaad")
```